# Multilayer UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Hello fellow developers,

I have been searching everywhere for a project that shows a good example of a multilayered (not sure how to describe the layers) scrollview with an offset. Similar to the Victoria Secret iPad application shown in this video http://vimeo.com/30783282. Honestly the app is better looking then some of those models.

It would be GREATLY APPRECIATED!!!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't entirely sure which 'layering' you were referring to, so I'll just comment on one possibility, which is the one seen at 13seconds in to the video you referenced.

You can have two `UIScrollView`s, with the same frame (i.e. one above the other). On the lower one set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`, and don't set its delegate either. For the upper `UIScrollView`, set the delegate and on the `scrollViewDidScroll` callback, adjust the frame of the lower UIScrollView by the desired amount.

Comment: Do you know of any example projects/ have any example projects you would be willing to share?
Again, much much appreciation.

Comment: Ok I just tried this out, I can see both my views pretty well, but how do I get the lower view to scroll as well? And do you know how to get them to scroll at different speeds?

Comment: In the `scrollViewDidScroll` callback, set the contentOffset of the lower `UIScrollView`. To make the lower `UIScrollView` move slower, make it, say, half the width the upper `UIScrollView`, and set the contentOffset.x to be the same percentage in both.